# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 supports the begin catch keyword I need to know microsoft SQL Server 2000 which keyword replace that

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

One of the stored procedures run on Microsoft SQL Server 2005 using `begin catch` command, but we need to move this microsoft SQL Server 2000 this keyword not working, if any one experience of that. Please help with this

Comment: SQL Server **2000** is **beyond dead** - **high time to upgrade!**

Answer (score 0):

Use this keyword `@@ERROR`

No. Try Catch block was introduced in SQL Server 2005.

The following article shows how you can use `@@ERROR` to check for errors:

[Understanding error handling in SQL Server 2000](https://web.archive.org/web/20080630054059/http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-6079583.html)

Answer (score 0):

In legacy systems, I'd simulate a try catch with xact_abort and goto

```
-- do stuff

if @Error <> 0 –if error

is raised

    begin

    goto handle_error

    end

    handle_error: IF @error != 0
Begin
 -- rollback and error mesage
end
```